# Is there a way to detect if a scale_linetype_manual has been added to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggnewscale

I need to be able to detect whether a ggplot passed into a function already has a `scale_linetype_manual` added to it so that I know whether to use `ggnewscale` and add another `new_scale("linetype")` to it.

Comment: Will it cause a problem to call `new_scale("linetype")` if you don't already have one?

Comment: I have ran into an edge where it does make a difference. Either bug in my code or bug in ggnewscales if that is not intended behavior.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. If you have a mre and it seems like a bug in the package, might be good to post it as an issue on GitHub.

Comment: ggnewscale mantainer here. If you feel you found a bug, please do open an issue with a reproducible example. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function should do the trick:

```r
has_linetype_manual <- function(p) {
  x <- sapply(p$scales$scales, function(x) x$aesthetics == "linetype")
  y <- sapply(p$scales$scales, function(x) as.list(x$call)$scale_name == "manual")
  if(length(x) == 0) FALSE else any(x & y)
}
```

So, setting up an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, linetype = Species)) + geom_density()

p2 <- p1 + scale_linetype_manual(values = c(4, 5, 6))

p3 <- p1 + scale_linetype_discrete()
```

Of the above plots, only `p2` should give us `TRUE` when passed to `has_linetype_manual`

```r
has_linetype_manual(p1)
#> [1] FALSE
has_linetype_manual(p2)
#> [1] TRUE
has_linetype_manual(p3)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>